# Forms and ORM - iterate over all fields and check if they're not empty

Tags: symfony

I'm using form classes, and doctrine ORM. What I want to do is to iterate through all form fields inside the controller, checking if it's not empty - and if it's not, persist it to the database.

Controller:

```
$form = $this->createForm(...);

$form->handleRequest($request);

if($form->isValid())
{
   $data = $form->getData();

   foreach($data as $field)
   {
      if(!empty($field)) $user->set{$field}($field); // set value to ORM
   }
}
```

Or something like that. I have a lot of fields, and I don't really want to do this manually. Is there a way to do that?

In my example, `$data` variable is an object, and I can't find the way to iterate over getter methods there.

Comment: If you created the form using the `$user` object then it will be populated by the `$form->handleRequest`. If you want to make sure the field are not empty then you should add some validation constraints (see: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html ).

Comment: By not empty I mean - if I fill 2 out of 30 fields, I want to change only 2 fields in the database, and leave 28 unchanged.